# Netbeans JavaSE components size different when executed

Tags: java, fonts, netbeans-8

I was wondering why the GUI editor on Netbeans 8.2 displays the components way smaller than they will be when the program is executed, you can see the difference [image: here] (left is in editor and right is in execution).

If there is no fix for this, is there a way to change the default font of the components ? It's set to `Tahoma 11 Simple` and I would like the size to be at least 18.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the `main` method to get it as you are seeing in designer preview

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: No, the look and feel changes the style but does not change the size of components (Although I'll change my picture so that theres no confusion)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but the displayed sizes of some of the components are larger than in the designer.  This causes the alignment to be off, since I align them in designer. It appears that the component that has a defined size (Properties -> preferredSize [136, 266]) seems to display exactly the same size. But I would rather not go through each of my dozens of component and set the preferredSize to see if that works.

Comment: If you can confirm that the solution described in your comment is actually a solution for the question/problem at the top of this page, then please [edit] to move the solution into the answer post. If however your answer post is a "i have a similar problem", with a solution as described in the comment, without being a solution fo the post on top, then please delete your post. All answer posts here have to be answers to the question at the top, not answers to different, though similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and a solution: The problem is by default, the application uses Nimbus as the Look and Feel. But the Design View uses a Look and Feel that is not Nimbus, so it looks different. To change the Design View LAF in NetBeans 14, go to Tools -> Options and select the Appearance tab. Then select the Look and Feel tab and select Nimbus from the drop down. NetBeans then has to be restarted.  Note that earlier versions of Netbeans put the LAF setting in a different place.